# Testing and training data in machine learning

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, mlp

i have more than 2000 data sets for ANN. I have applied MLPRegressor in it. My code is working fine. But for testing, i want to fix my testing value for instance i have 50 data sets. From that i want to test first 20 value. How do I fix this in the code? I have used the following code.

```py
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

df = pd.read_csv("0.5-1.csv")
df.head()

X = df[['wavelength', 'phase velocity']]
y = df['shear wave velocity']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.2)

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error

mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(30,30,30))

mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this for reproducible results, you can pass `train_test_split` a fix random seed so that in each run, same train/test samples are used. The benefit if using `train_test_split` would be to choose train/test splits nice and clean with no further effort.

But if you insist on manually choosing train/test split like you said, you can do it this way:

```
X_test, y_test = X[:20], y[:20]  # first 20 samples for test
X_train, y_train = X[20:], y[20:]  # rest of samples for train
```

Comment: can you suggest me any better idea to get the better data except manually choosing train/test split?

Comment: @SadiaMitu what do you mean by better data?

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to use train/validation/test splits and while training, keep an eye on validation loss + train loss. This way you can tell whether the model is overfitted on training data or not. For data split the best you can do is to ensure validation/test splits are representative of entire dataset. The size of these splits depend on size of dataset.

Answer (score 0):

fix the random seed for numpy as 48 or something else

```
np.random.seed(48)
```

this will generate identical splits every time. And use testsize for fixing the size of the split